# How to make it so that when pressed hotkey + anything else the hotkey worked?

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

I'm writing a script for game, i need to bind some key for pressing right click for three times. I can do it, but if i will use it in game i can press WASD or something else when i using hotkey and it doesn't work.

My code here :

```
import keyboard
import mouse
import time

iswork = False
def work():
    global iswork
    if iswork:
        iswork = False
        print("Script deactivated")
    else:
        iswork = True
        print("Script activated")

keyboard.add_hotkey("F4",work)
def RRR():
  if iswork :
      for i in range(3):
          mouse.right_click()
          time.sleep(0.05)

bind = input("Bind for Right - Right - Right :")
#keyboard.add_hotkey(bind,RRR)
while iswork:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("x") and len(keyboard._pressed_events) >= 1:
        RRR()
    elif keyboard.is_pressed("x"):
        RRR()
      
while True :
    count = 0
```

Comment: When (and for how long) do you expect your while-loops to loop? Have you tried `bind`ing `"x"` to `RRR` instead of the while-loop stuff?

Comment: I expect that my RRR function will work once per "x" pressing, but i can use some keys like WASD at the same time I press x, and I need it to work even when other buttons are pressed.
If u can give me example of the code